Biblatex and French elision in particles
When dealing with French authors who have a particle de, there is an inconsistency in treatment when the vowel is elided. Everything works as expected when the de is followed by a consonant, as in de France – there is a space, and biblatex recognizes it as a name prefix. But when de is followed by a vowel, as in d'Orléans, there is no space between the two, and it is not recognized as a prefix. This is a problem when placed in the beginning of a sentence, and with the \Citet command: the initial d of d'Orléans is not capitalized, whereas it is in de France.
Is there a way of making d'Orléans behave like de France, or will I have to reformulate and avoid such references at the beginning of a sentence.
\documentclass{scrartcl}            
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,useprefix=true,natbib]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{orleans,
  author       = {d'Orléans, Jean},
  title        = {Some Nice Title},
  date         = {2015},
  publisher    = {P. Ublisher},
  location     = {Place},
}
@book{france,
  author       = {de France, Jean},
  title        = {Some Nice Title},
  date         = {2016},
  publisher    = {P. Ublisher},
  location     = {Place},
}
\end{filecontents*}   
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}  


\begin{document}  
Wanted:

D'Orléans (2015) wrote something about d'Orléans (2015).

De France (2016) wrote something about de France (2016).

Result:

\Citet{orleans} wrote something about \citet{orleans}.

\Citet{france} wrote something about \citet{france}.
\printbibliography  
\end{document}   



If you input the d' with a following space, it will be recognised as a name prefix and treated just like de, but the space will be dropped in the output so that you get d'Orléans as expected.
\documentclass{scrartcl}            
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,useprefix=true,natbib]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{orleans,
  author       = {d' Orléans, Jean},
  title        = {Some Nice Title},
  date         = {2015},
  publisher    = {P. Ublisher},
  location     = {Place},
}
@book{france,
  author       = {de France, Jean},
  title        = {Some Nice Title},
  date         = {2016},
  publisher    = {P. Ublisher},
  location     = {Place},
}
\end{filecontents*}   
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}  

\begin{document}  
\Citet{orleans} wrote something about \citet{orleans}.

\Citet{france} wrote something about \citet{france}.

\printbibliography  
\end{document}


